# Webservice Not showing my methods

Tags: wcf, web-services, web-reference

I have made a web-service which'd give me the User Information.

```
[WebMethod]
public void Get_User_Info(string uid)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["contest"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from mtblUser where UserId=@UserId", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = uid;
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

}
```

this web service is having 1 method Get_User_Info(). but when I try to use this method the namespane show 4 methods like below

```
Get_User_InfoRequest

Get_User_InfoRequestBody

Get_User_InfoResponse

Get_User_InfoResponseBody
```

how can I use my method please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
YourService.ServiceSoapClient _CurrentSrv = new YourService.ServiceSoapClient();
_CurrentSrv.Get_User_Info(YourId);
```

Comment: now it is showing my method.

thanks, could you please brief about ServiceSoapClient ?

why we need this?

Comment: You inititialize your service object throught that. If the answer meet your needs point as accepted :). Also you can see this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996507.aspx